# Unable to access nested subfolder in HMVC CI

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I just created two folder in modules **(ui and admin)**...unable to call the controller in url.

http://localhost:82/myproject/ui/home/userlogin

```
ui (folder)
 -home (folder)
    - home (controller)
      - userlogin (method)

admin (folder)
 -dsb (folder)
    - dsb (controller)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in HMVC because HVC works based on module, and you are targeting in url  like ... https://localhost/site_name/module_name/method_name

module name having same name controller if you put again a sub module in module this will be not targeted. and more over I  suggest this is not good practice to do with HMVC

Answer (score 0):

Try change folder struct to

- ui (folder)

  - home (folder)

    - controllers (folder )

      - home (controller)

        - userlogin (method)
    - models(folder )
    - views(folder )

Comment: its not working...you r doing same mine code. 
`404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.`